# Should a Windows Installer / MSI shortcut component be tied to a registry key/value?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I see there are a lot of different practices with regard to how to have an installation package install a shortcut. One of these is to use a registry value as a key path for a component that principally contains a shortcut:

```
<Component Id="cmpShortcut1">
    <RegistryValue Root="HKMU" Key="Software\Acme Inc\Foobar" Name="shortcut1" Type="integer" Value="1" />
    <Shortcut Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Id="shortcut1" Name="Foobar" Target="[#filFoobarExe]" />
</Component>
```

This is what I see most of package authors do. The way I interpret it is that the lifetime of the shortcut component is tied to the lifetime of corresponding registry value. Is that a correct interpretation? Is that then a good practice? I could remove the shortcut file from wherever it was installed, and if the installation is attempted to be repaired, the mere presence of the "shortcut1" value in Registry will have the repair procedure forego reinstallation of the shortcut, because it thinks it is still installed (which it knows by looking for and finding the registry value). That's not very sound, is it?

Digging deeper into Windows Installer internals, in particular the tables it uses, and locating corresponding elements, arguments and relationships in Wix, I can also define a shortcut component as follows:

```
<Component Id="cmpFoobarExe">
    <File Id="filFoobarExe" KeyPath="yes" Source="!(wix.SOURCEDIR)\mpc-hc64.exe">
        <Shortcut Directory="ProgramMenuFolder" Id="shortcut1" Name="Foobar" />
    </File>
</Component>
```

Now, from what I understand, the component is now actually tied to the file itself, while the shortcut is tied to the component, according to [the documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/shortcut-table#Component_).

The above variation appears far rarer in the wild than the first approach, it seems, for one reason or another.

I should add the perhaps obvious bit that the two different definitions cause different relations in different MSI tables.

Given how Windows Installer apparently gives certain degree of freedom on how to implement shortcut installation, what is the consensus on how to best do this -- shortcuts have been and still are very fundamental parts of any installation, so I suppose one could hope this is a solved problem by now? And what is the difference between these approaches in practice, beyond the implications I have already managed to highlight?

I don't understand the wisdom and the logic behind associating a shortcut with a registry value in such a way where it isn't even a preference -- if the value in the registry could be meaningfully used to control or determine whether the shortcut is or should be installed, that'd be something. But the way it is with WI now, it seems it's some form of appendage that's also a limitation due to how WI was designed to deal with components?

On the other hand, the second approach, doesn't seem to offer the option to install the target file -- the application executable which typically is a mandatory feature in any installation -- but without the shortcut. It's both or neither? That's hardly great -- I'd want to design the package in a way where the installing party can choose whether they want a desktop shortcut, for example.

Comment: For a simple shortcut point to a file I'm installing I keep it simple.  For something pointing to something I didn't install it gets trickier.  Did your read this page? https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_uninstall_shortcut.html

Comment: and the original: http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/how-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the/